# map relationship between object in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, meteor

I am using meteor for development which using mongo db as store. Thats means that all operations are just display object value (frontend) or operate object (backend). For example, from [user] collection "copy" value (userId) to [message] collection but different key name. is there any way better to 
describe the relationship between two object rather than using

```
message.userId = user._id
```

maybe using a object to describe

```
{"userId","_id"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat. This is how I would do it.

I would first create a mapping object with key-value pairs which represent the field relations between the two objects. The keys are the keys from the first object and the values are the keys from the second object.

```
{
    "userId":"_id",
    "userName":"name"
    //...
}
```

Then I would use a function like this to apply the mapping object to two objects:

```
function applyMapping(fromObj, toObj, mappingObj) {
    for (fromKey in mappingObj) {
        var toKey = mappingObj[fromKey];
        toObj[toKey] = fromObj[fromKey];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,I thought similar solution as you. I dont know will ES6 help us for done this job already